# Keras Multilayer Perceptron train data show loss = nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have data in data_2.csv like this.

```
a   b   c   d        e         outcome
2   9   5   10175   3500        10000
1   3   4   23085   35000       34000
2   1   3   NaN     23283.33333 50000
....
```

I try to train with MLP. Column outcome is target output. This is my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C://data_2.csv')

sc = MinMaxScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(df.drop('income', axis=1).astype(float))

test= df[['outcome']]

y = sc.fit_transform(test.astype(float))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=20, test_size=0.1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,input_shape=(5,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print("##########################################")
print(y_pred)
```

while I train data it show **loss: nan** like this

```
Epoch 1/200
45000/45000 [==============================] - 2s 48us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/200
45000/45000 [==============================] - 2s 38us/step - loss: nan
```

when finish training it show output like this.

```
##########################################
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 ...
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
```

X_train.shape is (45000, 5)
y_train.shape is (45000, 1)
All output are NaN. How to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use `sigmoid` instead of `rectified linear units` ? In my opinion, your code tried to process numbers that are astronomically large. Try changing even the first `relu` into `sigmoid` and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prominent problem in your code is that you aren't cleaning your data. Neural Networks behave, in simple terms, by multiplying each node on each layer (that's a Dense layer). Then, imagine this: you have 32 nodes on the first layer, the largest positive number you have is about 35,000. If you multiply this 35,000 (more or less depending on weight and bias) by itself for 32 times, your number will be over the limit and will end up with NaN in just a few epochs.

Thus, your problem is with your activator, `relu`. This activator only filters the positive number (zero or greater) and turns any negative numbers to zero. With this activator, your initial nodes will have astronomical numbers!

I recommend changing your activator into a `sigmoid` function. This function scales a number between 1 and -1 (mostly). With this, your large inputs will be turned to numbers with absolute values of less than 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you want to stick to `relu` then you can only try to scale your inputs before inserting them.